# java jvm.dll path

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface

I'm building MS VC++ project that runs java via JNI.  I have installed several java versions on my pc (`jdk1.4` and `jre7`).

Environment variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
PATH=...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\jre\bin\server
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\include\win32
...
```

When I'm trying to call java statically it is trying to load jvm.dll from jdk1.4 and crashes(this is second problem). I know that it is searching for jdk1.4, because if I rename jdk1.4 install direcory project tells can't start because jvm.dll is missing. Why project is looking for jdk1.4? I have set environment variables to jre7 path.

If I load java dynamically, by telling which exact dll to load, everything goes fine.

Loading dynamically:

```
...    
HINSTANCE ghDllInstance = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_01\\jre\\bin\\server\\jvm.dll");
...
```